# override in typed racket

Tags: overriding, racket, typed-racket

If I want to override a class from typed racket to untyped racket, is it possible? if it is possible,I will be very much thankful if can anyone tell me how to override this below mentioned typed racket class to untyped racket class? I want to replace the text from "this is a frame" to "this is not a frame". 
Note: If any other possible option to replace the text, please tell me.

```
(: frame (Instance (Class #:implements Frame%
                          (augment [on-close (-> Void)]))))
(define frame  
  (instantiate
   (class frame%
     (augment*
       [on-close 
        (lambda ()
          (send board-canvas stop-timer)
          (inner (void) on-close) )])
     (super-instantiate ()))
   ("this is a frame") ))
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking when you say "override a class from typed racket to untyped racket." Do you mean create an untyped subclass of a class defined in typed racket? Or do you want to convert the code in your question to untyped racket? Or do you just want to create a class that overrides a method? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: suppose, this class is in a typed racket file. I want to include this file in an untyped racket file . I want to convert this piece of code to untyped racket file and then want to override such a way that it can replace the text "this is a frame" to any other text. so when I run the untyped file , it will show me the replaced text as output.

Comment: What do you mean? The code in your question doesn't define a class; it defines an object. The `"this is a frame"` text is a property of the object, not the class. Is that what you meant to do, or did you mean to create a class with a default value for that argument?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner I don't have enough knowledge . I just want to replace the text in untyped racket file. How can I do it?

Comment: Narrow it down: Do you need to use this typed code as-is and use it in an untyped file?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your typed code, you define `frame` as an object, not a class. This is because you used `instantiate`.

Normally you override things from *classes*. So to override that in another class, you'll need to lift the `(class frame% ...)` expression out of the instantiate form and define it as its own subclass. Once it has a name, you can use it multiple times.

For what you want to do, you don't need to override anything, you just have to instantiate this class multiple times with different values.

```
;; This class has been lifted out into its own definition, 
;; and given a name so that it can be used multiple times
(define my-frame%
  (class frame%
    (augment*
     [on-close 
      (lambda ()
        (send board-canvas stop-timer)
        (inner (void) on-close))])
    (super-instantiate ())))

(: frame (Instance (Class #:implements Frame%
                          (augment [on-close (-> Void)]))))
(define frame  
  (instantiate my-frame% ["this is a frame"]))
```

Once you have the subclass in its own definition, you can `provide` it from the typed file

```
(provide my-frame%)
```

And then use it in the untyped file:

```
#lang racket
(require "the-typed-file.rkt")

(define frame-2
  (instantiate my-frame% ["a different frame label"]))
```

This has nothing to do with overriding, however. It's simply giving a different value to the constructor in different places.

Comment: Thank you so much. That explains a lot. I have another question, if I want to keep the frame name same in both files  (not frame-2, only frame), is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely give the objects the same name, as long as you don't try to define or import both names in the same file.